# is there a way in Master Data Service to freeze a record (like make it disable) once a certain attribute is equal to Yes?

Tags: master-data-services

I'm using Master Data Service to collect data from different departments. So each group will have one or many attribute groups with update access.

I've an attribute that indicates the cycle completion as Yes or No value, once the value is set to Yes, I need to disable the records or to stop any from modifying this record. is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

This is what I would suggest.

1. Create a separate "reference" entity of sorts for let's say "Status", this will have only 2 records: Yes and No.
2. Convert the column Cycle Completion to a domain attribute referring to the newly created entity - "Status".
3. Now create a Derived Hierarchy where original entity is categorized by Status (on column Cycle Completion). So Status comes first, under that the original entity.
4. Once you have this derived hierarchy, you can set security access for all rows of original entity.. by values of "Status" entity, i.e Yes and No.
5. All you now need to do now is for all rows with "No" as the value in Cycle Completion, set access to Read-Only.

Now, as soon as the value of Cycle Completion is changed to "Yes" and the record is saved, it should become Read-Only.

You haven't specified the version of MDS (or SQL Server) you're using but I think this should work in all of them.

Comment: My next question is? previously everyone used to access the MDS by going to Entityand then picke the target entity, I think after proivding the new solution they should access the page through Hierarchies, True?!

Comment: another question please? now I've in my master file records with status (Active & Archive) what is need to transfer all those to a table for backup and then I need to delete from my master file the ones status as Archive to enchance performance, keep in mind what ever new created,updated need to be transfered to the copy table for not for the deleted? is this possible and is it possible to schedule it?. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Great to hear that it worked for you. Please do consider marking it as the "Answer" and up voting it. Thanks :)

To answer your 2nd question: yes, they can use either - Hierarchy or Entity view. I would suggest you advise them to continue to use Entity view, its what they already know, The security model will take care of figuring out which rows have to be provided modify / read-only access for the user. But yes, Hierarchy view has better UI, it distributes rows. In case they don't want to look at Archived rows then they can directly jump to Active. Completely upto you/ them.

Comment: For the 3rd question, I'm not sure if I completely understood it. For the benefit of the community, could you ask that as a separate question on stackoverflow, provide some additional details & I will be happy to help where I can. Just remember to add the tag [master-data-services]

Comment: SilverTry, very much appreciated. I'll open a new question in regards to my 3rd question. Thanks for everything.